# Should plainly incorrect answers be deleted?

Tags: discussion

This [very interesting question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34622/how-to-derive-rt-ct-circledast-frac12-h-bt-tau) has [an answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34648/80) that relies on the dubious assumption that the frequency response of time-varying systems exists in continuous time.

I believe the answer is blatantly wrong and should not appear on the site and should be deleted. However, since I've been involved in the discussion in the comments there, I don't think it's up to me to do that.

I've given a specific example, but my general question is:

- **Should plainly incorrect answers be deleted?**

and as a follow up:

- **What happens if they are the accepted answer?**

Comment: Just for the sake of argument: when should an answer be deleted vs downvoted? An answer with many downvotes could be a kind of warning to readers that, even if the answer may seem sensible at first sight, the community believes it is actually wrong.

Comment: @MBaz I've deleted answers in the past when they are spam, self-promotion, or duplicate answers to multiple questions. You make a good point, though: we should let the voting process run it's course... I'm just not sure there are enough voters on his question to get a good read. It's a little theoretical.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that some answers need to be deleted (I've flagged a few myself). I was thinking about answers such as the one you linked. Personally, I've never downvoted a question because of the reputation hit (I know that's silly). Maybe I should start with this one....

Comment: From the comments of that answer, it was clear that it was disputed, which is a warning sign to the reader.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo “The four stages of acceptance:
1. This is worthless nonsense.
2. This is an interesting, but perverse, point of view.
3. This is true, but quite unimportant.
4. I always said so."

Answer (score -1):

For the interested readers: [this](https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/Chapters_PDF/Fundamentals_Wireless_Communication_chapter2.pdf) is the "blatantly wrong" reference that is cited and defines the frequency response of the time varying channel (Eq 2.20). Author's page [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse).

Furthermore, please look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34710/is-cross-correlation-between-stationary-random-signal-and-noise-zero-for-all-lag/34721#34721) and the comments therein, then you will find out Wikipedia is also wrong. Note that it is admitted by the author in a comment that his answer is wrong.

Comment: -1 Nowhere in the comments do I say my answer is wrong. It is correct.  I'll update my answer to show where the term cross-correlation comes from and why the sample cross-correlation, which Wikipedia uses, is only an estimate of  the "true" cross-correlation.

Comment: "the =0 part isn't" [correct]. My comment refers to the =0 part only. I have no confusion with cross and autocorrelation. Also you need to locate the "wrong" in wikipedia.

Comment: I believe there is a wide-spread misunderstanding of where cross-correlation came from, any why the two definitions differ. Please see the update to my answer on that question and see if that helps.

Comment: Again: My problem is **only** with $=0$ part of your "definition" in (1), (3), and (4). Why is changing of subject? Is cross-correlation always zero by definition?

Comment: perhaps because you didn't make yourself very clear. Thank-you for the clarification.